# Движение элемента в эллипсе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем доброго дня. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать данную задачу.
Глаза в смайлике должны следить за курсором. 
У меня получилось реализовать движение глаз в окружности, а мне нужно, что бы область движения была ограничена эллипсоидом. В примере я показал реализацию своего варианта и сделал блок, на котором показал необходимую область движения глаз.
codepen.io/d-batmanov/pen/JOVRdB

Comment: https://github.com/jfmdev/jqEye

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/78ktpaqv/11/